# parse string as date-time

Tags: django, datetime

Let's say I have the following string:

```
Sat, 14 Sep 2013 22:44:49 +0000
```

how would I turn it into the following format for Django models?

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ]
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `datetime` to achieve what you are looking for

```
from datetime import datetime 
date_string = "Sat, 14 Sep 2013 22:44:49 +0000"
initial_format = "%a, %w %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z"
final_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z" 

datetime.strptime(date_string, initial_format).strftime(final_format)
```

You can construct the [appropriate formats here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Alternatively, for django models, you could just send datetime object as a parameter, and django would convert it to the appropriate format for you.